# Is there a way to, using library functions, remove the last element of a list?

Tags: prolog

Say that I want to remove the last element of a list. I can do it with `append/3`:

```
append(WithoutLastElement, [_], List)
```

However, this leaves behind a choicepoint! Try `append(X, [_], [1, 2])`, for example.

I can write my own predicate (taken [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32027317/306))

```
list_butlast([X|Xs], Ys) :-
  list_butlast_prev(Xs, Ys, X).

list_butlast_prev([], [], _).
list_butlast_prev([X1|Xs], [X0|Ys], X0) :-  
  list_butlast_prev(Xs, Ys, X1).
```

But I wonder if there's a way to use a built-in, the `append/3` solution has the advantage of taking about 2 seconds to read and understand what is happening. `list_butlast_prev` requires a little more thought.

I'm using SWI-Prolog and would appreciate answers which work there, but I'm also curious if it's possible in other Prologs.

Comment: @false, why did you remove the swi-prolog tag? I'm asking specifically about whether it's possible to do this using swi-prolog's library

Comment: The question is not specific to SWI. You said: *I'm using SWI-Prolog and would appreciate answers which work there, but I'm also curious if it's possible in other Prologs.* So not even you want an answer specific only to SWI.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `append/3` in conjunction with `->/2`, i.e.:

```
(append(WithoutLastElement, [_], List)->true)
```

For example wrapped in a procedure:

```
list_butlast(List, ListWithoutLast):-
  (append(ListWithoutLast, [_], List)->true).
```